# Mutable Sorted Set in Scala doesn't work I expect (maybe I'm missing something)

Tags: scala

Let's say you have the following:

```
case class Foo(x: Int, y: Int) extends Ordered[Foo] {
  override def compare(that: Foo): Int = x compareTo that.x
}

val mutableSet: scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[Foo] =
    scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet(Foo(1, 2), Foo(1,3))
```

I expect the result of `mutableSet.size` to be `2`. Why, `Foo(1,2)` and `Foo(1,3)` are not equal but they have the same ordering. So the sorted set should be (IMO) `Foo(1,2), Foo(1,3)`. As this is the order they were created in (even the other way around would be fine, counter intuitive but fine).

However, the result of `mutableSet.size` is `1` and it saves the last value i.e. `Foo(1,3)`.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is similar to the Java SortedSet collections. `SortedSet` uses compareTo in order to define equality, thus it eliminates the same Foo case classes from your example.

In Scala 2.11 it uses `scala.collection.TreeSet` for the implementation SortedSet implementation. The best way to figure out this is to put breakpoint into your `compareTo` method.

TreeSet is implemented using AVL Tree data structure, you can inspect the behavior by looking into the [AVLTree.scala](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/scala-2.11/library/scala/collection/mutable/AVLTree.scala.shtml) insert method of the Node class. It compare `compareTo` result with 0 in order to figure out does it duplicated element in the collection.

Comment: I wish the scala documentation gave some details like the java documentation of sorted set does. Reading the java docs of sorted set it is very clear that this is the behavior. When I experienced this issue I immediately checked the scala docs to see if it talked about this behavior. Now it's clear...thanks :-). Btw, taken from the java docs "The behavior of a sorted set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface." So I guess it makes sense I was confused ;-)

Comment: Well, the Scala documentation does already say that `compare` must be consistent with `equals` , so I'm not sure how much help extra documentation saying the same thing would be.

Answer (score 2):

You have overridden `compare` so that only the first field is used in comparison. The Set uses this `compare` function not just to sort the items but also to determine if the items are equal for the purpose of storing them in the `Set`.